# Unable to resolve dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When starting Android Studio, I get this error:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.

Comment: Can you post your app module's `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux on a new project you may get this error after installation Android Stidio if you haven't did this step ([as described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)):

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

`sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have properly defined repositories in your build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

or

There's some issue with internet connection.