# Unable to resolve dependencies in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been getting unable to resolve dependencies error after updating the gradle to 5.1.1. I have tried all the possible solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218535/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv) and this [one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199352/unable-to-resolve-dependency-in-android-studio). But couldn't fix my problem.

This is my error log :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
```

And this is app level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.FirstApplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is project's `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Regards

Comment: post your project's build.gradle

Comment: @Darish I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

In you project level Gradle
change google() position like my example.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for gradle `5.1.1`.

I don't agree with tips from Deepak with putting `google()` last. Historically I need it first due to other problems.

Also, your `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` is redundant due to already having `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`.

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#add-library) you can remove

`maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
       }`

as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was I am working in a restricted area. So there was blocking of files being downloaded. And some how the gradle was not able to download all the dependencies. I just ran everything in open internet connectivity and it all works like a charm.

So I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697118/android-studio-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target) to allow the packages to be downloaded in the restricted environment. Still if it didn't resolve your issue if you are working in a restricted environment contact your network guy.